# Is size_t portable?

Tags: c, portability, 32bit-64bit, size-t

GCC 4.4.1, C99

I am using `size_t`, and `size_t` is an `unsigned int`. However, that depends if you are running 32 bit or 64 bit.

I will be using `size_t` to store the size of a buffer.

So I don't think this would be very portable if using across architectures.

Just a question, with using `size_t` on either a 32 or 64 bit. What situations would cause the most serious problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`size_t` is guaranteed to be able to hold the number of bytes of any object on your implementation.
That's why the return type of `sizeof` is `size_t`.

So yes, it's portable.

Comment: size_t is portable as long as you're not attempting to save size_t type variables to binary files or send them across network connections.  The second you start doing that it's about as portable as a very unportable thing that's been super-glued to the floor.

Answer (score 10):

As others have said, `size_t` is correct and perfectly acceptable for storing the result of `sizeof()` or the size of any representable object in bytes.  What you have to watch out for is the following:

1. `size_t` is the same size as *some unsigned integer type*.  It is not necessarily the same number of bytes as the largest unsigned integer type, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, etc.
2. `sizeof(size_t)` is an implementation-defined number of bytes so `memcpy`'ing it or assigning into any integer type other than `uintmax_t` is a bad idea.  I'm not even sure that it is safe to assume that it is of equal size or smaller than `uintmax_t`.
3. Writing a `size_t` value to a binary file and reading it back into a `size_t` by another process, on a different machine, or by something compiled with different compiler options can be hazardous to your health.
4. Sending a `size_t` value across a network and trying to receive it using a `sizeof(size_t)` buffer on the other side is rather unsafe.

All of these are standard issues with any other integer type except `unsigned char`.  So `size_t` is just as portable as any other integer type.

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to figure out what you mean by "portable" in this case. The term "portable" allows multiple significantly different interpretations.

`size_t` has a very specific purpose. It can hold the size of any object in the given implementation. I.e. it is a type that can always receive the result of the `sizeof` operator. `size_t` has no other purpose, and within its intended application, it is 100% portable, as portable as anything can be.

What kind of "portable" you are asking about is, once again, not clear.

Comment: I am using size_t to get the size of a buffer. I doing some messaging with socket programming and the source code will be compiled on both linux and windows. I will have to get the size_t of the data that has been sent from the client. Thanks

Comment: @robUK, you should add this important piece of information to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It makes some sense to use size_t or ssize_t for a buffer if you're using malloc() or read(). For portability use SIZE_MAX, SSIZE_MAX, sizeof(type-in-your-buffer) and %zd or %zu printf().

Comment: Unfortunately, Microsoft's C compiler does not support the `z` size modifier for `printf()`.

Comment: `z` modifier is a part of C99 standard. Microsoft compilers so far used C89/90. In C89/90 the "portablility" of `size_t` printing must be implemented manually.

Comment: Those bas..., I forgot. Well, he did ask about C99. I guess he really asked about the "most serious" problem which would be either Linux's optimistic allocation, or blithely assuming (count*sizeof()) doesn't overflow, or maybe thinking you need to allocate that much memory in the first place.

Comment: Microsoft supports the `z` length modifier as of Visual Studio 2015. A few other length modifiers are supported.  See topic `<stdio.h> and <conio.h>` in  [C Runtime (CRT) Features, Fixes, and Breaking Changes in Visual Studio 14 CTP1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/06/18/c-runtime-crt-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-14-ctp1/)

Answer (score 1):

You've also got off_t and ptrdiff_t / ssize_t, which vary between architectures in the same way.

If you use them correctly, then they are portable across architectures. On a 32-bit system, they'll all be 32 bits wide, while on a 64 bit system they will all be 64 bits wide. This is what you want - the size of a buffer can't possibly be any larger than a 32-bit size_t on a 32-bit system, but it can be far larger on a 64-bit system.

You should never use ints, longs, or anything else. Aside from anything else, the size of a long varies depending on the platform (32-bits on most 32-bit systems, 64-bits on 64-bit Unix systems, 32-bit on 64-bit Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are using size_t for.

If you use it to determine the size of a memory buffer it will be safe, since size_t is large enough to address the whole memory of any computer. So if the memory buffer is larger than that, you have a problem anyway.

On the other hand, if you use it as a generic unsigned integer to count the number of stars in the universe for example, you might have a problem on 32-bit system (not sure about 64-bit systems).

Comment: Not true. `size_t` is sufficient to hold the size of the largest object supported bythe implementation. `size_t` is *NOT* large enough to address the whole memory. For the latter you'd need `intptr_t`/`uintptr_t`.

Comment: I stand corrected. But still, the largest object is what you probably need in that case, or else you have another problem.

Answer (score -2):

The only real serious problem with this is trying to access a rather large array or a large number for size_t.

Just like just a regular "int" might be enough on a 64-bit, but could cause a crash on a 32-bit because its too large for a int on a 32-bit system.